# Using Past tense of verb to know current status

Tags: sentence-construction

After the completion of my lecture, can I say the sentence below?

> a) I hope you **learned** something today from my speech.

or should I say,

> b) I hope you **have learned** something today from my speech.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of those are acceptable and idiomatic. In this case, they are essentially equivalent in meaning.

Comment: But Generally we use Verb + ed to refer past tense. so how my first example can be used to tell current status?.

Comment: Lots of past tense statements say something about present status. Once you learn something, that is a (theoretically) permanent change. Lots of the time, English doesn't have much difference of meaning between past and perfect.

Comment: Is learned is past participal rathar than past tense here ?

Comment: In A it's the simple past, in B it's the participle.